# Dash in Javascript date

Tags: javascript, datetime

I suppose this is absolute novice question in javascript.

I want to know what do '-' mean in javascript date.

Example: new Date(2010, 12 - 1, 10, 22, 00, 00);

What does 12 - 1 say in the above.

Thanks

Comment: Too bad, cant accept more than one answer...:(...Thanks guys...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's subtracting one to get `11`.

Why? It's usually the result of an earlier month number being "off" one, because [`.getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) is 0-based, where other date parts are 1-based.  The signature for `Date()` looks like this:

```
new Date(year, month, date, hour, minute, second, millisecond)
```

...but the `month` parameter is `0-11`, where the `year` and `date` parameters are `1-based`.  You think of `12` as December, but being 0-based, it's `11` not `12`...the code style you're seeing is one way to express that or at least make you go "wait a second..." and see that it's not `November`, as you'd intuitively think if the author just put "`11`" there.

Answer (score 3):

12 - 1 == 11, a simple math expression.

It's used to notify code's reader that this date falls on December.

Since months in Javascript are 0 based (0 - January ... 11 - December), this way it's easier to see what the author meant.

This idiom also exists in Java. And since Javascript "borrowed" the name from Java, it wouldn't be a surprise if it borrowed some more ;-)

A for loop with an index starting from 0 is a common idiom, so `Date`'s authors have probably used code like this:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < 12; ++i) {
    console.log( new Date( 2010, i, 1));   
}
```

Looks typical, but is awkward to use when 0 based indexing isn't natural, like with months.

Answer (score 2):

It's a simple mathematical operation (12 - 1 = 11).

Comment: In that case when I execute it, it says "Fri Dec 10 2010 22:00:00". If it is mathematical operation, the month should be Nov.